# How to get largest number of consecutive integers in a substantially large array (spread across multiple machines)

Tags: arrays, distributed-computing, distributed-system, system-design

I was asked this question in an interview. The first part was fairly simple in which I had to write a code to get maximum number of consecutive integers in an array. Following is the code that I wrote:

```
int count = 0, max = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if((array[i - 1] + 1) == array[i])) //curr is consecutive to prev
          count++;
    else
          count = 0; //reset the counter as sequence is broken

    //Keep track of maximum
    if(count > max)
         max = count;
}

System.out.println(max); //print the length of largest consecutive integers
```

The second part was follow up question on it:

How would you modify this logic to work for arrays that are stored in multiple machines?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it using the [Reduce Parallel Pattern](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/parallel-pattern-7-reduce/222000718)

Example in Python (sorry for bad namings):

```
def longest_seq(seq):

    Result = namedtuple("Result", ["left", "left_n", "max_n", "right", "right_n", "is_const"])

    def _longest_seq(seq):
        if 1 == len(seq):
            x = seq[0]
            return Result(left=x, left_n=1, max_n=1, is_const=True, right=x, right_n=1)

        l_res = _longest_seq(seq[0: int(len(seq) / 2)])
        r_res = _longest_seq(seq[int(len(seq) / 2): len(seq)])

        left_n = l_res.left_n + r_res.left_n if l_res.is_const and l_res.right == r_res.left else l_res.left_n
        right_n = r_res.right_n + l_res.right_n if r_res.is_const and r_res.left == l_res.right else r_res.right_n
        max_n = max(l_res.max_n, r_res.max_n, l_res.right_n + r_res.left_n if l_res.right == r_res.left else 0)
        is_const = l_res.is_const and r_res.is_const and l_res.right == r_res.left

        return Result(left=l_res.left,
                      left_n=left_n,
                      max_n=max_n,
                      right=r_res.right,
                      right_n=right_n,
                      is_const=is_const)

    return _longest_seq(seq).max_n
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we are distributing the whole array left to right to each machine sequentially. For example, for only two machine(`machine1` and `machine2`), we will distribute array `0.... i` to `machine1` and `i + 1....n` to `machine2`. From each machine, we can return several additional information along with local maximum.

```
class result {
    public int machineId;
    public int maxSoFar; // the max value as your code
    public int leftElement; // the leftmost element
    public int leftLength; // number of times the leftElement appears consecutively in left
    public int rightElement; // the rightmost element
    public int rightLength;  // number of times the rightElement appears consecutively in right
};
```

During merging two machine's result, for any two machine whose `machineId` are consecutive(e.g. 3 and 4), we can maximize like this -

```
return Math.max(((machine1.rightElement == machine2.leftElement) ? machine1.rightLength + machine2.leftLength : 0), 
                  Math.max(machine1.maxSoFar, machine2.maxSoFar));
```